# Highest rank within a range - two matching data sets in range

Tags: google-sheets, ranking

I have a column that looks like this in a spreadsheet for a Fantasy F1 League. I need to find a way to give 5 points to the 1st mention (highest position) of each team car. For example, P1 Mercedes gets 5 points. P3 Mercedes gets 0. P2 Ferrari gets 5 points, P21 Ferrari gets 0 and so on so it looks like this:

```
mercedes 5
ferrari 5
mercedes 0
red_bull 5
haas 5
toro_rosso 5 
red_bull 0
williams 5
williams 0
mclaren 5
renault 5
sauber 5
manor 5
sauber 0
force_india 5
force_india 0
manor 0
toro_rosso 0
haas 0
mclaren 0
ferrari 0
renault 0
```

Is there a way of doing this in Google Sheets?

The information will be pulling from an API and the position of each team will change week on week.

Comment: Try `=(countif(A$1:A1, A1)=1)*5`

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much. So so simple, I just couldn't see it. You're a lifesaver!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In **B1** enter ***5***
In **B2** enter:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A$1:$A2,A2)=1,5,0)
```

and copy down.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much, a massive help. Thanks again :)

Comment: @user1721451  Thanks for the feedback.